# Ubuntu now always starts in overview mode when logging in. How to avoid?

Tags: gnome, login, activities-overview

Recently, Ubuntu 21.10 (Gnome 40.4.0, logging in with GNOME on Xorg) has started displaying the overview mode when I log in (normally, tapping Super achieves this). The first thing I have to do then is press Esc to return to normal.

This is the first time I have seen such behaviour, and it's unwanted. How can this be avoided?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

there seems to be few extensions for this.

simple one is https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4099/no-overview/

Install this extension from above link by choosing version number 40.

[image]

Comment: Perfect! The next question is of course why on earth Gnome would make such a ridiculous change :(

Comment: There is a post about this on other forum. I am not able to identify it now. But there is a strong reasoning in that post.

Comment: We are all different, but I'd still like to see why this reasoning is considered strong! If you can locate it, please inform me here :)

Comment: I remember the main reason is user can click which app they want to open from the dash favourite icon and it automatically exit the overview. I will search the post n send you soon.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/najbgt/gnome_40_get_rid_of_activitiesoverview_startup/